# Querying page and Scraping it using Sheets

Tags: regex, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, wikipedia-api

I wanna use Sheets to query pages from wikidata and scrape a specific section but I couldn't find anything focused specifically on this, and since I'm a beginner in this I don't know really where to start from.
So, I have a list of Q identifiers and I'd like to use them to query the page, and then check if there's a specific section there (or scrape the data from it if possible) otherwise return false. I started with what I found [here](https://gist.github.com/VladimirAlexiev/8201d614a819cb7d4023ce9aa315af65)

```
=ImportXml(concat("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageprops&
ppprop=wikibase_item&redirects=1&format=xml&titles=",G1),"//@wikibase_item")
```

but used instead the link for wiki data (it generates a working link, but I'm not sure if this works as the equivalent of an API and if I can further query it to get data) and the wiki Property code that I wanna get (date of death, /wiki/Property:P570), but I get the "Imported content is empty." error, for this [link](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q18579064). Ideally, I would've like to get the date of death value (20 November 2014), or at least a TRUE , meaning that the section exists, and the person is dead.

```
=IMPORTXML(CONCAT("https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/",A2),"/wiki/Property:P570")
```

So I might have some Q-links that don't have this section/property at all, and for which I should get an error, but I don't know why it's not working for this one either, do I have to make Xpath to div, or can I use the wiki Property?

I hope this makes sense, I'll put the sample sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V-YdEPvIi8s-ryonwe_eKS0dheCQqu2Ff0GGRLjLLfo/edit#gid=0). Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTXML("https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/"&A1, "//*"), 
 "select Col2 where Col1 = 'date of death' and Col2 is not null")
```

[image]

or:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTXML("https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/"&A1, "//*"), 
 "select Col2 where Col1 = 'date of death' and Col2 is not null")<>""
```

and for no match:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTXML("https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/"&A1, "//*"), 
 "select Col2 where Col1 = 'date of death' and Col2 is not null"), FALSE)
```

[image]

---

```
=IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(IMPORTXML("wikidata.org/wiki/"&A2, "//*"), 
 "select Col2 where Col1 = 'date of birth' and Col2 is not null"), 
 "(.*) \d.*reference.*"), FALSE)
```

Comment: It's an awesome solution. Do you have any idea which version of xpath is compatible with IMPORTXML?

Comment: @SIM gs uses the 1.0 version tho not all quirks are fully supported so lets say its 0.85 ;)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using a combination between the first one and last one

Comment: and adding a Regex to extract just the year (without the reference part). =IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(IMPORTXML("https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/"&A2, "//*"), 
 "select Col2 where Col1 = 'date of birth' and Col2 is not null"),"(.*)\d.*reference.*"),FALSE)